# Missing Python Package Download Data from PyPI in 2016

Tags: python, pypi, trend, popularity

Here is a plot of monthly download data from PyPI's old system pypi.python.org and new data storage on BigQuery.

[image]

[Total Downloads of Module Missing on PyPi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37531231/total-downloads-of-module-missing-on-pypi/37531550) mentions that, Donald Stufft (PyPI maintainer in 2016 (is Donald still in charge?)), disabled the broken PyPI's download count system. Donald also mentioned in the email that "this isn't a permanent loss of the feature and we won't lose any data".

My question is that is where I can find the "missing" data from late 2015 to 2016?
 Is the raw data stored somewhere?

update 1: another related question [Why PyPi doesn't show download stats anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38102317/why-pypi-doesnt-show-download-stats-anymore/38102521)

*Footnote: the graph is a raw measure of user downloads but is far from accurate due to 1. PyPI data is cumulative downloads for each file, BQ data is the accurate download data. 2. non-PyPI sources are not counted, such as Anaconda, etc other ways to install packages.*

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[image]

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as download_count
FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE(
  [the-psf:pypi.downloads],
  TIMESTAMP("2019-09-15"),
  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
)
WHERE file.project="sharks"
```